# Django Tutorial: Runserver not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am starting to dabble with Django, and am having issues with the tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/)

I have successfully installed the framework. After running the migrate command, and starting the server with this command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Powershell outputs:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 27, 2014 - 16:32:54
Django version 1.7.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

So everything seems to be working fine. The tutorial tells me that:

> Now that the server’s running, visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` with your
>   Web browser. You’ll see a “Welcome to Django” page, in pleasant,
>   light-blue pastel. It worked!

But when I go to that link, I get the following message show up on my browser:

> ERROR
>
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
>
> The following error was encountered:
>
> Connection to 127.0.0.1 Failed The system returned:
>
> ```
> (111) Connection refused The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.
> ```
>
> Your cache administrator is root.

I am new to web development so I apologize for asking a rookie mistake, I just can't seem to find this issue with the django tutorial online, so I must be pulling a seriously rookie move!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must have caused keyboard interrupt after running the server.

Comment: Is your browser on the same machine as the server is running on?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tanveer - what exactly does that mean/any recommendations to resolve this? @Daniel, yes it is.

Comment: After running python manage.py runserver are you pressing ctrl + c.

Comment: No, I am not quitting the server, the moment I receive that message about 'starting development server at http....", I check on my browser to see the page, where I get that error message on my browser instead of a welcome page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the problem is proxy? Look for this.

Comment: Good man Simeon - I did not realize I had a proxy set up on the browser. Thanks everyone!